# main thread sleep will waiting for an event in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, serial-port

i have a serial port object with dataRevised event, i need to have my main thread sleep will waiting for the event to fire dataRevised event, i used semaphore but when the main thread on waiting the event won't fire, i need the solution to be as fast as can be and i am using C# in .NET 2.0.
in other word i need the the code:

```
lock(_lock){
     _serialPort.write(cmd);
     ans=_serialPort.read();
 }
```

to run from start to finish without interrupt, the problem is that i need to wait for the incoming data so there will be something to read.

Comment: code? (please) What have you done so far? It's handy so we have a bit more context.

Comment: i can't write the exact code here but to put is Simply i need Nonoverlapped I/O so the code:
lock(_lock){
_serialPort.write(cmd);
ans=_serialPort.read();
}
will run from the start to finish without interrupt.

Comment: you don't need to write the *exact* code here.  The wonderful thing about S.O. is that almost all of us understand keeping company software sufficiently secret.  What you're talking about exposing is a *very* small thing.  If someone can answer *how* to do it, then chances are it's not sufficient enough to break your confidentiality agreement.  Also, learning to expose the right amount of code is an incredibly useful skill.  I'd highly recommend you try (and learn) as S.O. will be infinitely more useful to you that way.

Comment: What S.O stand for ?
also what about what i wrote in my update?

Comment: S.O. == Stack Overflow, and that's a bit better...what have you tried already?

Comment: i since moved on but the question still hunt my, how do i make a specific thread to by fired up by an event ?

Answer (score 1):

> i need to have my main thread sleep will waiting for the event to fire dataRevised event
>
> but when the main thread on waiting the event won't fire

Clearly you *can't* have your main thread sleep because the event won't fire if you do that.  You need to rework your application such that your main thread doesn't need to sleep until the event is raised.

Comment: i thout of something along the lines of passing delaget of the event to the thred and make him wait for the event isn't any way to do something like that ?

Comment: @user1120007 Not if you're doing a blocking wait, no, as the event can't fire if the main thread is blocked.  You need to be doing non-blocking waits instead.

Comment: i changed my desgine so this will be the case, for personal interest how make a thred take the event ?

Comment: @user1120007 I don't understand what you mean by "take the event".

Comment: that the event will fire up a method which is my thred